# Fix bathroom corner tile

Tags: bathroom, ceramic-tile

Take a look at the picture, it is the corner of bathroom floor and shower pan/base.

How can I fix it and also seal it so water ( not from shower, but in case there is a water on bathroom floor from cleaning or something ) don't go inside.

I am talking about floor tile, not the base trim tile.

I can always use thin set mortar but don't want to buy entire bucket/box, for such a small job. Any alternatives?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The picture tells me that long-term water damage has softened the floor below the hexagonal tile in that area and caused the tile to break and subside. The tile in that area needs to be pulled up and the floor underneath (the *substrate*) needs to be repaired prior to any attempt at re-tiling. And (this should go without saying) the leak needs to be fixed.